# Zend Framework 2 Standalone Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

Is there a tutorial on how to use "zend form" without the whole framework ?

I'm using Zend Framework 2. I manage to use Zend\Config\Reader\Ini to read the configuration and pass the config to Zend\Form\Factory using "fromFile()" method, but after that I don't even know how to render the form. I use "Twig" for my template engine so I need to output the form I create to Twig token.

The way to do it change drastically from Zend Framework 1 and I check the tutorial it only show the way to do it when you use their full mvc framework .

Can anyone help ?

In Zend Framework 1 I remember we just do it like this

```
$form = new Zend_Form(new Zend_Config_Ini('some_config.ini');
$form->render (new Zend_View());
```

What is the equivalent/similar method for Zend Framework 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's different in zf2, instead of one render() call as in zf1, now you have to echo each form element and the form's open and close tag in your view script. So, in your controller:

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form;
$form->append(new \Zend\Form\Element\Email('email'));
return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
```

and in your view script:

```
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
foreach ($form as $element)
       echo $this->formRow($element);
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
```

Comment: That's what I didn't found, what is the instance of $this->form, I use zf2 as individual module not the whole. I already generate the $form what is the step to generate the html layout on the same script ?

Comment: @WiryonoLauw I added the code for creating the form object. If you only use zf2 by modules, you can just use put them in one file. Just remove the 'return' line.